# NuGet and nightly builds

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, nuget

Should we put our nightly builds on NuGet daily? Customer asked for this but they are a big number of packages per year. Is NuGet designed for this purpose? How can we mark stable releases instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from putting your nightly builds on NuGet. Some teams, such as the ScriptCS team and the ASP.NET team use [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery) for nightly builds instead of using the main NuGet feed.

You will probably want to distinguish these builds from stable releases, at least on the main NuGet feed. You would need to mark these builds as pre-release NuGet packages using a version number such as **1.0.1-alpha1** and use 1.0.1 for the stable release. However if you use MyGet you would not need to mark these builds as pre-release if you did not want to.

Comment: @Alberto Nuget supports multiple package sources. You can even host your own nuget server with nightly builds. Only customers that add this feed on purpose will get your nightly builds.

Comment: @SchlaWiener: Will we be able to replace the previous nightly package with todays one? We aren't interested in keep hundreds of packages...

Comment: @Alberto - I added a answer with some details

Comment: MyGet is basically a different source of NuGet packages. You could host a NuGet server yourself or use a third party hosting site, such as MyGet, to host your packages if you do not want every package on NuGet.org

Comment: @Matt: I was wondering if I can replace packages instead of adding a new one daily...

Comment: I do not believe you can replace packages on NuGet.org. You can replace them if you host NuGet yourself since the packages are stored within a directory. I believe you can replace packages on MyGet. At least there is an option "Forbid overwriting of existing pakcages" which is off by default.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, think from the users point of view.

Even if a customer installs your nightly, he will be able to go back to a more stable nightly if something breaks. For this an absolute requirement is a unique version scheme for every build that you publish.

Let's say your customer has version `1.0.1-nightly.1234` installed which works for hin. Now he does an update to `1.0.1-nightly.1235` which is broken and he can not continue. He should be a able do do

```
uninstall-package YourPackage
install-package YourPackage -version 1.0.1-nightly.1234 -pre
```

I understand that you don't want to mess up nuget.org with your nightly builds so you could either use another feed or setup your own sever (maybe your build server already can do this, I use teamcity which can do nuget deploys and has a build in nuget server, even if I never used it so far but am planning to do so).

Maybe you can do a monthly pre-release on nuget.org or manually publish nightly builds that you consider fairly stable.

I would suggest you change your version scheme to include a date in your builds `1.0.1-nightly.20140520` for your own feed and `1.0.1-nightly` for the official build.

nuget itself supports versioning schemes like `<major>.<minor>.<patch>-<buildname>.<revision>` but nuget.org only allows `<major>.<minor>.<patch>-<buildname>`

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning